# Call an Common API on above each API in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular11

I want to call a Session API on each API call to check the session of the user according to the session API response, another API will be called, but I don't want to put it on each API that creates code redundancy.

The solution will be helpful.

Comment: You could look into Angular [`HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

Comment: But calling session API in the interceptor becomes recursive.

Comment: Please show the recursive code.

Comment: If I call an API inside the interceptor again that API calls the interceptor and this thing is recursive.

Comment: Normally your API checks whether a transferred token is valid. If it's not the case you redirect to a login page which tries to relog the user in. You should *not* call another (Session) API on every request.